# Django Inline Formset - possible to follow foreign key relationship backwards?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to django so I apologize if this has an obvious answer.

Say you have the following three models:

```
models.py

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Product(models.Model):
    plu = models.Charfield()
    description = models.Charfield()

class Template(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    price = models.DecimalField()
```

The inline formset would look something like:

```
TemplateFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Customer, Template, extra=0, 
                fk_name='customer', fields=('price'))
```

Is it possible to follow the Template formset's Product foreign key backwards so you could display the plu and description fields within the same table?

For example something like this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
  {% for obj in customer.template_set.all %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ obj.product.plu }}</td>
      <td>{{ obj.product.description }}</td>
      <td>{% render_field formset.form.price class="form-control form-control-sm" %}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The formset's fields appear with the html above but the data from the bound form instance doesn't appear and I can't save by editing the empty fields.

I've also tried below but each formset is repeated for each object (for x formsets there are x*x rows):

```
<tbody>
{% for obj in customer.template_set.all %}
  {% for form in formset %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ obj.product.plu }}</td>
      <td>{{ obj.product.description }}</td>
      <td>{% render_field form.price class="form-control" %}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

[Basically I'm trying to go from the top portion of the image to the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vl7FZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working although I'm not sure its the most efficient way. If anyone has a better way please let me know.

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
<table>
  <thead>
  ...
  </thead>
  <body>
  {% for obj in customer.template_set.all %}
    {% with forloop.counter as outer_counter %}
      {% for form in formset %}
        {% if forloop.revcounter == outer_counter %}
          {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %} {{ hidden }} {% endfor %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ obj.product.plu }}</td>
            <td>{{ obj.product.description }}</td>
            <td>{% render_field form.price class="form-control" %}</td>
          </tr>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Should also mention I'm using django-widget-tweaks which is where `{% render_field %}` comes from.

Update (the proper way):

```
{% for template in customer.template_set.all %}
  {% for form in formset %}
    {% if form.instance.id == template.pk %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The formset functionality is only to show forms but something that you can do is create a custom form that display the 2 fields with the function of `readonly` like:

```
class your_form(models.ModelForm):
     class Meta()
        model = Template
        fields = ['price', 'product']

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(ItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['product'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

TemplateFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Customer, Template, extra=0, 
                fk_name='customer', form=your_form)
```

That's my best tried, if you wanna display both try returning in your models something like:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    plu = models.Charfield()
    description = models.Charfield()

    def __str__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        a = '<td>' + self.plu + '</td><td>' + self.plu '</td>' 
        return self.plu + self.description # Or return 'a'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm looking to add quite a few fields to the table which would be pretty difficult doing it like this.